# How can I define a variable inside a function?

Tags: php

how I can define a variable inside a PHP function and make it reachable from another function? I want to set $error variable to "1".

This how would the code look like:

```
   function checkthename ($name){ 
    if ($name == "TESTTEST"){
    echo $error = 0;
    }
    else {
   echo $error = 1;
    }
}

function phone ($phone){ 
    if ($name == "TESTTEST"){
    echo $error = 0;
    }
    else {
   echo $error = 1;
    }
}
```

etc.

And in end of the code there would be an another function which is checking if there is any $error variable set to 1

```
    function checktheerror($error){ 
    if ($error == 0){
    echo "no error in this code";
    }
    elseif ($error == 1){
   echo "there is one or multiple errors";
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: That can be done using _global variables_, but you should really rather try to avoid using those. Your function should _return_ a value instead, and then you assign that to a variable outside of the function scope: `$error = checkthename($foobar);` And then you call your `checktheerror` function with that variable as parameter, as you are already doing.

Comment: You can create a class with all of these functions, such as a Validation class, and make `$error` a property of the class, that all of the functions have access to.

Comment: Where do you have this piece of code? Do you have just a php file with functions without Object-oriented programming ?

Comment: @aynber are you mean this way? thank you!
`$name = "TESTTEST";
$phone = "1234";
class validate {
public $error;
function checkthename($name){
if ($name == "TESTTEST"){
/// ITS OKAY
}
else {
// IF NOT OKAY SET ERROR TO 1
$this->error = 1; 
}
}

function phone($phone){ 
if ($phone == "1234"){
/// ITS OKAY
}
else {
$this->error = 1; 
}
}
}
$validate = new validate();
$validate->checkthename($name);
$validate->phone($phone);
echo $validate->error;`

Comment: It's really hard to read in comments, but it looks like you have the idea, yes.